# MariaDB, Python read_sql_table, utf8-bin

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I've go a MariaDB Server and I try to connect and get data into a pandas dataframe in python.

The MariaDB looks like the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE `fhem` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

with the tables `current` and `history`.

```
CREATE TABLE `fhem`.`history` (TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DEVICE varchar(64), TYPE varchar(64), EVENT varchar(512), READING varchar(64), VALUE varchar(128), UNIT varchar(32));
```

I can succesfully connect in python:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as db
engine = db.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pass@192.168.37.33:3306/fhem')
data = pd.read_sql_table('history', engine)
```

the Dataframe has the correct header:

```
['TIMESTAMP', 'DEVICE', 'TYPE', 'EVENT', 'READING', 'VALUE', 'UNIT']
```

But the cells don't have the correct format. They look like

```
[50, 50, 46, 51]
```

and should be something like

```
"on" or "off"
```

If I do a query in the terminal with *mysql -u user .. SELCET * from history;* I get the correct data.
I tried to add

```
engine = db.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pass@192.168.37.33:3306/fhem', encoding='utf8')
engine = db.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pass@192.168.37.33:3306/fhem?charset=utf8')
```

But that did not help either. The only column that is display correctly is `TIMESTAMP`.

What I can do is the following:

```
for l in data['VALUE'].values:
    x = l.decode('utf-8')
    print(x)
```

I could do this for every column that interests me and than add it to a new df but I guess there has to be better way. Can you help me?

**EDIT**

I have the following options:

```
print(data['VALUE'])
```

[image]

```
for l in data['VALUE']:
   print(l)
```

[image]

```
for l in data['VALUE']:
  print(l.decode('utf-8'))
```

[image: This is how it should look]

The last one, is the df I am aiming on.
I tried

```
data['VALUE'].apply(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
```

which does nothing.
I am running on pandas 0.23.4 and sqlalchemy 1.2.12

Fabian

Comment: sample data would help understand what may be wrong.

Comment: It is not a good idea to stuff a list in a cell.

Comment: I don't want the list. The Database contains a string, not a list (like the last picture). I don't understand, why there is a list in the cell at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had my System running on a VM Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have now switched to Windows with Anaconda and Python 3.6 and there is no such problem. I get the correct values in the first time.

Fabian